# Greenplum windows service for import data

Tags: windows, greenplum

I have installed windows service on my local machine and all setup looks good. However when I read from external table, I get http response code 500.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TEMPORARY TABLE A
(
    a smallint,
    b integer,
    c text  
)
LOCATION ('gpfdist://hostname:8081/filename.txt')
FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER AS '   ' null '' ESCAPE 'OFF') ;
```

Error message -

```
ERROR:  http response code 500 from gpfdist (gpfdist://hostname8081/filename.txt): HTTP/1.0 500 session error (url.c:326)  (seg538 slice1 sdw135:40002 pid=6237) (cdbdisp.c:1476)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible chance of permission / access issues. check your stream provisioning setup.

User who is creating External table should have permission to write and access the directories over ETL nodes where you've started your stream provisioning.